# Auth Timeout with MVC5

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET identity with MVC5 and want to expire logged in users after a set period. I've added a section to system.web in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="1" slidingExpiration="false"/>
</authentication>
```

I've also changed the login code to not use a persistent cookie:

```
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);
```

But the user is never logged out, they just stay logged in forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a difference between forms auth and ASP.NET Identity. The web.config settings don't have any effect if you're using Identity.

The settings for Identity are in App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(24),
        SlidingExpiration =false
    });
```